# How to sum parent and child record when grouped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

A `Message` has the attributes `location`, `like_count`, `vote_count`.

And a `Comment` `belongs_to :message` and has the attributes `like_count`, `vote_count`

I have managed to figure out how to hash out the `location` along with the number of votes the `Message` was given in that particular `location`.

```
@votes_by_place = Message.where(
:user_id => @user.id).select(
:location).group(:location).sum('like_count + vote_count')

# => "Total votes and likes of your Messages posted in New York, United States ": 192
# => "Total votes and likes of your Messages posted in Paris, France ": 93
```

I could just keep it like this and it'd be fine, but I'd really really love it if I could find a way to sum the `vote_count` and `like_count` of `comments` with `user_id => @user.id` and in a specific `@message.location`

So that it would become:

```
# => "Total votes and likes of your Messages and Comments posted in New York, United States ": 192
# => "Total votes and likes of your Messages and Comments posted in Paris, France ": 93
```

Perhaps it would be easier if I assigned `location` to `Comments` as well?

Let me know what you think and any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this in a single query, but with two queries and a little plain Ruby it can be done. Maybe someone else can find a more efficient way.

```
with_comments = Message.where(user_id: @user.id).
  left_outer_joins(:comments).
  group(:location).
  sum('messages.like_count + messages.vote_count + comments.like_count + comments.vote_count')
```

This first query adds all of the `like_count`s and `vote_count`s from both the `messages` and `comments` tables for `messages` that have associated `comments`. Using `left_outer_joins` ensures that the call to `group` adds hash keys for all message locations including those that don't have associated comments, so all the user's message locations are represented.

```
without_comments = Message.where(user_id: @user.id).
  left_outer_joins(:comments).
  where(comments: { message_id: nil }).
  group(:location).
  sum('messages.like_count + messages.vote_count')
```

This second query adds all of the `like_count`s and `vote_count`s from only the `messages` table for `messages` that don't have associated `comments`.

```
totals = with_comments.dup

totals.each_key do |location|
  totals[location] += without_comments[location].to_i
end
```

`dup` the first hash and iterate over it, adding up the values of both hashes and converting `nil` values to `0`.

Comment: I finally managed to get this to work. Regardless if there's a better way to do it,  this is the for now the right answer. This covers all the aspects if there's a message that doesn't have a comment, and all comments regardless if it belongs to a particular message. Million thanks!

Comment: Glad it helps! @Crashtor

Answer (score 1):

You can do this query.

```
SELECT location, SUM(comments.vote_count + comments.like_count) as total_vote_and_like FROM messages
JOIN comments ON messages.id = comments.message_id
GROUP BY messages.location
```

For ActiveRecord:

```
@votes_by_place = Message.select("messages.location, SUM(comments.vote_count + comments.like_count) as total_vote_and_like")joins(:comments).where(user_id => @user.id).group("messages.location")
```

I hope this will help you.

You can go to this link to get detail http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65bb32/6.

Comment: I think I got it to work by using joins(:comments) however, when I try to output it in the view, it only prints `#<Message:0x007fd3a41c8fc0 >`

Comment: No.. This sums ALL the comments which have the same @user.id.. Not the comments in each `message.location`

Comment: I see. I forgot to add joins(:comments).